# Error while git p4 cloning the branches with --detect-branches

Tags: git, perforce

When I trying to detect branches from Perforce I am getting the below mentioned error.

```
git p4 clone --detect-branches //depot/path/abc_987/migration/@all
```

The error I am receiving is

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`git p4` expects your P4 project to use Unicode.  *Expects* is perhaps a bit too strong, but if it does use Unicode, you'll be fine.  You aren't fine which means you are not using Unicode.

In [commit `f7b5ff607fa1a62a480399afb6ccb9691735bf79`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7b5ff607fa1a62a480399afb6ccb9691735bf79), Tao Klerks added a number of improvements to the `git p4` encoding handling.  However, this does not appear to be released anywhere (no existing Git tag contains this commit, though it's in the `master` branch).  You might want to clone the Git repository for Git and try the `master` branch's code on your repository, though.